# An error occurred while running the simulation and the simulation was terminated

Tags: matlab, errors

I created a Stewart Platform Simulink model, but I am getting the following error. This especially happens when you connect the outputs from the mux to the 4th and 5th legs in the general block diagram. There is no problem when I do not connect them. Can anyone help me?
[image]

[image]

[image]